# Float4 not faster than float in cuda

Tags: c, cuda

**Edit:** njuffa is right this version was compiled with -G which disables all optimizations. The new SASS is way faster as loads and stores are vectored.

Based on classic examples, I have modified two versions of vector addition in cuda. The thing is, the float4 version is twice as long as the float version with 4 times less data size. Profiling both kernels shows clearly the float4 version is performing on average 4 loads and 4 stores per transactions while float version does only one for both. It sounds like a noob question about misaligned access to float4, which BTW is confirmed by PTX below, but I can't find where.

I am using Cuda 7.0 rc with quadro K4000.

Any ideas on where to look?

Compile options ?

```
__aligned__ keyword ?


__global__ void add_float(float *c, const float *a, const float *b)
{
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}

__global__ void add_float4(float4 *c, const float4 *a, const  float4 *b) {

    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    float4 a1 = a[i];
    float4 b1 = b[i];

    float4 c1;
    c1.x = a1.x + b1.x;
    c1.y = a1.y + b1.y;
    c1.z = a1.z + b1.z;
    c1.w = a1.w + b1.w;

    c[i] = c1;
}
```

PTX on the line:

```
float4 a1 = a[i];
```

says:

```
...
ld.f32 %f1, [%rd6];
ld.f32 %f2, [%rd6+4];
ld.f32 %f3, [%rd6+8];
ld.f32 %f4, [%rd6+12];
st.f32 [%SP+12], %f4;
st.f32 [%SP+8], %f3;
st.f32 [%SP+4], %f2;
st.f32 [%SP+0], %f1;
...
```

The SASS objdump says:

```
    /*0108*/                   MOV R10, R0;                             /* 0x2800000000029de4 */
    /*0110*/                   ISET.LT.AND R11, R0, RZ, PT;             /* 0x108e0000fc02dc23 */
    /*0118*/                   MOV32I R13, 0x4;                         /* 0x1800000010035de2 */
    /*0120*/                   ISETP.LE.U32.AND P0, PT, R13, 0x20, PT;  /* 0x198ec00080d1dc03 */
    /*0128*/                   ISUB R12, 0x20, R13;                     /* 0x4800c00080d31e03 */
    /*0130*/                   SHL R11, R11, R13;                       /* 0x6000000034b2dc03 */
    /*0138*/                   SHR.U32 R14, R10, R12;                   /* 0x5800000030a39c03 */
                                                                        /* 0x22c2804282328047 */
    /*0148*/                   IADD R11, R11, R14;                      /* 0x4800000038b2dc03 */
    /*0150*/              @!P0 IADD R12, R13, -0x20;                    /* 0x4800ffff80d32003 */
    /*0158*/              @!P0 SHL R11, R10, R12;                       /* 0x6000000030a2e003 */
    /*0160*/                   SHL R10, R10, R13;                       /* 0x6000000034a29c03 */
    /*0168*/                   MOV R10, R10;                            /* 0x2800000028029de4 */
    /*0170*/                   MOV R11, R11;                            /* 0x280000002c02dde4 */
    /*0178*/                   IADD R8.CC, R8, R10;                     /* 0x4801000028821c03 */
                                                                        /* 0x228042c042828047 */
    /*0188*/                   IADD.X R9, R9, R11;                      /* 0x480000002c925c43 */
    /*0190*/                   MOV R8, R8;                              /* 0x2800000020021de4 */
    /*0198*/                   MOV R9, R9;                              /* 0x2800000024025de4 */
    /*01a0*/                   LD.E R10, [R8];                          /* 0x8400000000829c85 */
    /*01a8*/                   IADD R12.CC, R8, 0x4;                    /* 0x4801c00010831c03 */
    /*01b0*/                   IADD.X R13, R9, RZ;                      /* 0x48000000fc935c43 */
    /*01b8*/                   MOV R12, R12;                            /* 0x2800000030031de4 */
                                                                        /* 0x2202828042c2e287 */
    /*01c8*/                   MOV R13, R13;                            /* 0x2800000034035de4 */
    /*01d0*/                   LD.E R11, [R12];                         /* 0x8400000000c2dc85 */
    /*01d8*/                   IADD R12.CC, R8, 0x8;                    /* 0x4801c00020831c03 */
    /*01e0*/                   IADD.X R13, R9, RZ;                      /* 0x48000000fc935c43 */
    /*01e8*/                   MOV R12, R12;                            /* 0x2800000030031de4 */
    /*01f0*/                   MOV R13, R13;                            /* 0x2800000034035de4 */
    /*01f8*/                   LD.E R12, [R12];                         /* 0x8400000000c31c85 */
                                                                        /* 0x2282c202828042c7 */
    /*0208*/                   IADD R8.CC, R8, 0xc;                     /* 0x4801c00030821c03 */
    /*0210*/                   IADD.X R9, R9, RZ;                       /* 0x48000000fc925c43 */
    /*0218*/                   MOV R8, R8;                              /* 0x2800000020021de4 */
    /*0220*/                   MOV R9, R9;                              /* 0x2800000024025de4 */
    /*0228*/                   LD.E R8, [R8];                           /* 0x8400000000821c85 */
    /*0230*/                   IADD R14.CC, R2, 0xc;                    /* 0x4801c00030239c03 */
    /*0238*/                   IADD.X R15, R3, RZ;                      /* 0x48000000fc33dc43 */
                                                                        /* 0x22828042c2e28047 */
    /*0248*/                   MOV R14, R14;                            /* 0x2800000038039de4 */
    /*0250*/                   MOV R15, R15;                            /* 0x280000003c03dde4 */
    /*0258*/                   ST.E [R14], R8;                          /* 0x9400000000e21c85 */
    /*0260*/                   IADD R8.CC, R2, 0x8;                     /* 0x4801c00020221c03 */
    /*0268*/                   IADD.X R9, R3, RZ;                       /* 0x48000000fc325c43 */
    /*0270*/                   MOV R8, R8;                              /* 0x2800000020021de4 */
    /*0278*/                   MOV R9, R9;                              /* 0x2800000024025de4 */
                                                                        /* 0x22c2e2828042c2e7 */
    /*0288*/                   ST.E [R8], R12;                          /* 0x9400000000831c85 */
    /*0290*/                   IADD R8.CC, R2, 0x4;                     /* 0x4801c00010221c03 */
    /*0298*/                   IADD.X R9, R3, RZ;                       /* 0x48000000fc325c43 */
    /*02a0*/                   MOV R8, R8;                              /* 0x2800000020021de4 */
    /*02a8*/                   MOV R9, R9;                              /* 0x2800000024025de4 */
    /*02b0*/                   ST.E [R8], R11;                          /* 0x940000000082dc85 */
    /*02b8*/                   IADD R8.CC, R2, RZ;                      /* 0x48010000fc221c03 */
                                                                        /* 0x22820042e2828047 */
    /*02c8*/                   IADD.X R9, R3, RZ;                       /* 0x48000000fc325c43 */
    /*02d0*/                   MOV R8, R8;                              /* 0x2800000020021de4 */
    /*02d8*/                   MOV R9, R9;                              /* 0x2800000024025de4 */
    /*02e0*/                   ST.E [R8], R10;                          /* 0x9400000000829c85 */
```

Here is the rest:

```
void CudaTest()
{
    int size = 8192;

    float *dev_a = 0;
    float *dev_b = 0;
    float *dev_c = 0;
    float *host_a = (float*)malloc(4 * size * sizeof(float));
    float *host_b = (float*)malloc(4 * size * sizeof(float));
    float *host_c = (float*)malloc(4 * size * sizeof(float));

    float4 *dev_a4 = 0;
    float4 *dev_b4 = 0;
    float4 *dev_c4 = 0;
    float4 *host_a4 = (float4*)malloc(size * sizeof(float4));
    float4 *host_b4 = (float4*)malloc(size * sizeof(float4));
    float4 *host_c4 = (float4*)malloc(size * sizeof(float4));

    for (int i = 0; i < 4 * size; i++)
    {
        host_a[i] = rand() / RAND_MAX;
        host_b[i] = rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        host_a4[i].x = rand() / RAND_MAX;
        host_a4[i].y = rand() / RAND_MAX;
        host_a4[i].z = rand() / RAND_MAX;
        host_a4[i].w = rand() / RAND_MAX;
        host_b4[i].x = rand() / RAND_MAX;
        host_b4[i].y = rand() / RAND_MAX;
        host_b4[i].z = rand() / RAND_MAX;
        host_b4[i].w = rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }

    // Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
    CUDA_CALL(cudaSetDevice(0));

    // Allocate GPU buffers for three vectors (two input, one output)    .
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, 4 * size * sizeof(float)));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, 4 * size * sizeof(float)));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, 4 * size * sizeof(float)));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c4, size * sizeof(float4)));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a4, size * sizeof(float4)));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b4, size * sizeof(float4)));

    // Copy input vectors from host memory to GPU buffers.
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(dev_a, host_a, 4 * size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(dev_b, host_b, 4 * size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(dev_a4, host_a4, size * sizeof(float4), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(dev_b4, host_b4, size * sizeof(float4), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    int local = 256;
    int N = size / local;
    // Launch a kernel on the GPU with one thread for each element.
    add_float << <4*N, local >> >(dev_c, dev_a, dev_b);
    // Check for any errors launching the kernel
    CUDA_CALL(cudaGetLastError());

    add_float4 << <N, local >> >(dev_c4, dev_a4, dev_b4);
    // Check for any errors launching the kernel
    CUDA_CALL(cudaGetLastError());

    // cudaDeviceSynchronize waits for the kernel to finish, and returns
    // any errors encountered during the launch.
    CUDA_CALL(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    // Copy output vector from GPU buffer to host memory.
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(host_c, dev_c, 4 * size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(host_c4, dev_c4, size * sizeof(float4), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
}
```

Comment: What target architecture and CUDA version are you using to produce the PTX you have shown? On CUDA 6.5 I get the expected vectorized load and store instructions

Comment: PTX is just an intermediate format. To check whether vectorized loads and stores are present, inspect the machine code (SASS) extracted with `cuobjdump --dump-sass`.

Comment: I have added SASS objdump for Njuffa. Talonmies, I am not sure of what you talking about. I am building for K4000 quadro with cuda 7.0. Flags for nvcc are compute_30,sm_30.

Comment: The SASS code above suggests that you are compiling with the `-G` flag, which causes all optimizations (including vectorization) to be disabled.

Comment: Thank you Njuffa for pointing this out. It now works as expected.

Comment: @njuffa do you want to provide an answer?  I would upvote.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Thanks for reminding me of this question, I had failed to notice that the asker had closed the loop regarding my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Use of vector load/store instructions provided by the GPU hardware is considered a performance optimization applied by the compiler, as the code is fully functional using scalar loads and stores. When code is compiled by `nvcc` with `-G` (usually for debugging), all optimizations including the vectorization of loads and stores are turned off.

To check for load/store vectorization, it is important to look at the actual machine code (SASS) that is being executed, rather than PTX, which is merely an intermediate code that gets compiled into SASS by an optimizing compiler component called `ptxas` which is invoked by the driver program `nvcc`. Run `cuobjdump --dump-sass` on the executable produced by `nvcc` to inspect the machine code.